# jQuery modal form displayed before ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have coded such that when the plot button is pressed, it performs an ajax call & displays a plot in modal form. The button code, modal form code is presented here. Along with Ajax call. The problem faced is, it displays the modal even before the Ajax completes The alert is done function comes only after the modal is displayed. Also, it is not displaying modal after Ajax completes it.

id of the button is `plotbtn`

```
<div class="input-group col-1" id="plotdiv">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm text-center" style="margin-left:65px" id="plotbtn" name="plotbtn"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#plotModal">

    <span><i class="fa  fa-line-chart" style="font-size:24px;color:blue">Plot</i></span>
  </a>
</div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="plotModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="modaldialogchild" style="max-width: 100%;margin-left:5px">
        <div class="modal-content" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employee In Out Time For the week {{from_date}} -
              {{to_date}}
            </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="closebtn2" name="closebtn2">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body d-none" id="error1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  <div class="row vertical-align d-none" id="error2">
                    <div class="col-1 text-center">
                      <p id="plotp1">
                        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"></i>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-11">
                      <strong>Error:</strong>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employee In Out Time For the week {{from_date1}} -
              {{to_date1}}
            </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="closebtn3" name="closebtn3">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body" id="image1">
            <p>testing</p>
            <img src="\static\images\my_fig.png" alt="static/images/my_fig.png" style="width:100%;height:100%"></img>

            <!--img src="\static\images\my_fig.png" alt="\static\images\my_fig.png" style="width:85%;height:85%"></img!-->
            <!--img src="\static\images\cat1.jpeg" alt="ddf"></img!-->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <!--button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button!-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        ...

        $(document).ready(function () {
          var table = null;
          $('#srchbtn').bind('click', function () {
             ...
            });
            return false;
          });
          var table1 = null;
          //      $('#btn1').bind('click', function () {
          $('#a_nice_table').on('click', 'tr td.a', function () {
...
             });
            return false;
          });


          $('#a_nice_table').on('draw.dt', function () {
            $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();
...
          })

          $('#plotbtn').on('click', function (event) {
            //alert("in button click")
            $.ajax({
              data: {
                //sending data to backend
                //name: ('#employee_id').val()
                employee_id: $('input[name="employee_id"]').val()
              },
              type: 'GET',
              url: "/plot.png"
            })
              .done(function (data) {
                alert('in done after ajax');
                if (data.error) {
                  alert(data.error);
                  var str = $("#plotp1").first().text();
                  $("#plotp1").last().html(data.error);
                  $("#error1").addClass("d-block");
                  $("#error1").removeClass("d-none");
                  $("#error2").addClass("d-block");
                  $("#error2").removeClass("d-none");
                  $("#image1").addClass("d-none");
                  $("#image1").removeClass("d-block");
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $('#plotModal').modal({
                    show: false,
                    escapeClose: true,
                    clickClose: true,
                  });

                  //$('#plotModal').style.display = "block";
                  $('#plotModal').fadeIn('slow');
                  $('#plotModal').modal({ 'show': true });
                  $("#closebtn3").click(function () {
                    //alert("in close btn")
                    $("#div1").fadeOut("slow");
                    event.preventDefault();
                  });


                }
                else {
                  alert("in success")
                  from_date1 = data.from_date1;
                  to_date1 = data.to_date1;
                  console.log("success", data.from_date1, data.to_date1);

                  $("#error1").removeClass("d-block");
                  $("#error1").addClass("d-none");
                  $("#error2").removeClass("d-block");
                  $("#error2").addClass("d-none");
                  $("#image1").removeClass("d-none");
                  $("#image1").addClass("d-block");
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $('#plotModal').modal({
                    show: false,
                    escapeClose: true,
                    clickClose: true,
                  });

                  //$('#plotModal').style.display = "block";
                  $('#plotModal').fadeIn('slow');
                  $('#plotModal').modal({ 'show': true });
                  $("#closebtn3").click(function () {
                    //alert("in close btn")
                    $("#div1").fadeOut("slow");
                    event.preventDefault();
                  });

                }


              });


          });



        });
      </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Some observations: 1) there is a lot of code here, most of it seems unrelated to the problem you describe.  Try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help you understand the problem better, and make it much easier for everyone else to help.  2) I don't know if your code to `fadeIn` the modal will work. KISS - just try displaying it the normal way first (`$('#plotModal').modal()`).  Once it works, try experimenting with how you show it. ...

Comment: ... 3) Not a good idea to assign event handlers in your `.done()` callback - eg if you click your plot 2x times you will end up with 2x identical event handlers attached to `#closebtn3` which will *both* run on click.